# PyCharm returns incorrect Boolean value when comparing two "and" expressions

Tags: python, pycharm, boolean

I'm still pretty new to Python and this has got me stumped. I've got three computers all running PyCharm, they all are returning the same incorrect Boolean value. Here is the issue. I've been using PyCharm on both of my PC's and my MacBook Pro, so I don't think that it's a software glitch. I've been studying Automate the Boring Stuff, it asks to input these Boolean expressions:

`(4 < 5) and (5 < 6)`= True

`(4 < 5) and (9 < 6)`= False (This returns "True" for some reason)

`(1 == 2) or (2 == 2)`= True

Basically just showing how the and, or, not operators function.

The expression `(4 < 5) and (9 < 6)` returns as True every single time (in PyCharm). However, I can open Python, type the exact same expression and it comes back as False, as it should. Has anyone else experienced this? Could I be doing anything wrong?

Actual code:

```
print( 4 < 5 ) and (5 < 6)

print( 4 < 5) and (9 < 6)

print(1 == 2) or (2 == 2)
```

Comment: Can you share code? I am getting different results  than yours when I try

Comment: How weird, when I copy and paste your code I get "All good on the home front!" but when I use the print function I still get the same incorrect value. Does is have something to do with the print function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question and include the code you have tried, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: print( 4 < 5 ) and (5 < 6)
print( 4 < 5) and (9 < 6)
print(1 == 2) or (2 == 2)

Comment: @trev84 after testing with your code, I see the problem. You'd need to wrap the stmts with an outer paranthesis, so for example the first one becomes like `print(( 4 < 5 ) and (5 < 6))`.

Comment: In the example above, what you're doing is: 1) printing the result of the first expression, which always prints something 2) chaining the result of the `print` statement using or/and,  so the second expression always runs (as a `print` call always returns `None`) and doesn't output anything since it doesn't have a `print` around it.

Comment: You can confirm that `print` doesn't return anything either: `if print(1 < 2): print('Hooray!')` -- the second print statement will never be executed in this case, since `print` returns `None`.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Thank you so much! I appreciate you taking the time to help me get that figured out!

Answer (score 1):

The results seems to be as expected for me, using Pycharm - on Windows, however that shouldn't matter in this case.

```py
assert (4 < 5) and (5 < 6)
assert (4 < 5) and (9 < 6) is False
assert (1 == 2) or (2 == 2)
```

---

You also mentioned that one particular expression `(4 < 5) and (9 < 6)` is giving you trouble in Pycharm. Perhaps try running the below code? It seems to work as intended for me in Pycharm with the Run command - though I typically just use a keyboard shortcut for this purpose.

```py
if (4 < 5) and (9 < 6):
    print('Something went wrong! Please uninstall Pycharm :-)')
else:
    print('All good on the home front!')
```

Output:

```
All good on the home front!
```